# Multiple substring replacements for multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a dataset which contains special characters transformations in few columns because of the language of the data entry. 
I want to replace these special characters representations to Latin characters which are defined in the dictionary below.

```
replacements={"Ä±": "i", "Ä°": "i", "Ã‡": "c", "Ã§" : "c", "Ã¼" : "u", "ÃŒ": "u", "Ã¶" : "o", "Ã–" : "o", "ÅŸ": "s",
          "Å?" : "s", "ÅŽ" : "s", "ÄŸ" : "g", "Ä?" : "g", "ÄŽ" : "g"}
```

As it can be seen there are several replacements to be applied so that using replace() won't be a fancy coding. There might be more than one special character substring in one string therefore all of them should be executed for each string.
Moreover to that I need to apply them to several columns of the dataframe;

```
DF[['NAME','SURNAME','ADDRESS','EMAIL']].
```

Is it possible to write a fancy code to replace all the characters defined in the dictionary and apply to several columns?

Comment: Use `DF[['NAME','SURNAME','ADDRESS','EMAIL']] = DF[['NAME','SURNAME','ADDRESS','EMAIL']].replace(d, regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

replace can be thing, just iterate over it (it's not that fancy though)

```
def rp(x):
   x = str(x).lower()
   for key, value in replacement.items():
        x.replace(key,value)
   return x

df = DF[['NAME','SURNAME','ADDRESS','EMAIL']].apply(rp)
```